# Drag/drop between two datatables

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using [datatables](http://www.datatables.net) in my ruby on rails project. The data is being populated through ajax. I want to drag/drop rows between tables. Is there any plugin/hack to do it?

Answer (score 1):

you mentionned jquery yourself in tags. So use it !

http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/#shopping-cart

on the callback event you can update the other table